# TypeError: Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address payable[] storage ref

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, dapps, remix-tests

I am having  the above error at the point where I am pushing the newly created contract address into the contracts[] array. Where am I going wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

````
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Bakery {

  // index of created contracts

  address[] public contracts;
  Cookie public cookieContract;

  function getContractCount() 
    public
    
    returns(uint contractCount)
  {
    // return contracts.length;
  }

  // deploy a new contract

  function newCookie(string memory _name)
    public
    returns(Cookie newContract)
  {
    newContract = new Cookie(_name);
    contracts.push(newContract);   ///**Line Having Error***//////
    return newContract;
  }

  function getCookieName (Cookie _cookieContract) public returns(string memory name) {
      cookieContract = _cookieContract;
      string memory n =  cookieContract.name();
      return n;
  }
}


contract Cookie {

    //name
    string public name;

     constructor (string memory _name) public{
        name = _name;
    }

  // suppose the deployed contract has a purpose

  function getFlavor()
    public
    pure
    returns (string memory flavor)
  {
    return "mmm ... chocolate chip";
  }    
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `contracts` is declared as

```
address[] public contracts;
```

so it will only accept addresses.

You could fix it by casting `newContract` as address

```
function newCookie(string memory _name)
  public
  returns(Cookie newContract)
{
  newContract = new Cookie(_name);
  contracts.push(address(newContract));
  return newContract;
}
```